# How to filter Django's foreignKey form dropdown

Tags: django

I have a form that is used to edit (update) a record, and the `Author` field is automatically a dropdown, which is great, but how do you filter this list?
For example, the dropdown is populated with the entire user list. How can I filter this list so that it only shows the items where `isDevice == True`?

**accounts/models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    isDevice = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    ...
```

**builds/models.py**

```
class BuildQueue(models.Model):
    Author =  models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,blank=True, null= True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

**forms.py**

```
class BuildQueueEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BuildQueue
        fields = ['Author','project', 'customer',]
```

**views.py**

```
class buildQueueEdit(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = BuildQueue
    form_class = BuildQueueEditForm
    template_name = 'buildQueue_edit.html'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `UpdateView` inherited also from `FormMixin`, in your `buildQueueEdit` you can override [get_form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form), where form is instantiated and exactly where you can modify the form's field's `queryset`.

```
class buildQueueEdit(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = BuildQueue
    form_class = BuildQueueEditForm
    template_name = 'buildQueue_edit.html'

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['Author'].queryset = CustomUser.objects.filter(isDevice=True)
        return form
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to change text displayed in your dropdown you can override `choises` instead of `queryset`. It worked for me.

```
form.fields['Author'].choices = [(item.id, item.equipmentName) for item in CustomUser.objects.filter(isDevice=True)]
```

Comment: That worked thank you! - Do you happen to know how I would now change the attribute in the dropdown? It defaults to the user name. I tried using a for loop like

`query = CustomUser.objects.filter(isDevice=True)
for item in query:
    form.fields['plannedAuthor'].queryset = item.equipmentName
    return form`
it returns `'str' object has no attribute 'all'`

Comment: Hey @mrevgenx, any idea how to set the default value to `None`?